# My hobby is "to infinitive", does it sound strange to native speakers' ears? Is that true?

Tags: grammaticality

Watching [**this video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqnBhyw8128), a good English speaking Japanese is asking if when we say "My hobby is...", would it be nicer to use the to-infinitive or ing-gerund. The native speaker says, "My hobby is ...ing" sounds fine and "My hobby is to do something" sounds weird, but says it is still **"legal"**, does it hold true in ordinary conversation between native speakers?

Thank you. Please listen to the conversation from 3:10. No Japanese attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sound a little stilted, like the sort of conversations that high school students practice for oral exams, and not natural conversation.

In conversations with adults, I can't ever remember asking them about their "hobbies". People are probably more likely to say "I enjoy reading books" or "I like to read books" rather than "My hobby is reading books".

I agree with the video presenter, the use of the gerund is better, in most cases, when you say "My hobby is..."

Comment: Agreed. It's also worth noting that while the native speaker's conclusion was correct, his explanation was not. He suggested that gerunds and infinitives can both be used as nouns, therefore "logically" both should be correct after "hobby". But there are plenty of situations where only infinitive or only gerund is correct, including his own examples of "desire" and "hope", which can only take infinitive. A better explanation --thought perhaps less satisfying-- would be that gerund is the correct form, but for whatever historical reason, infinitive is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

<-- American English, native speaker.

I would always use the gerund in this case. Infinitive sounds weird.

> My hobbies are hiking, playing video games, and trolling people on Facebook.

James is perhaps correct that younger people especially do not explicitly label them "hobbies", but there's nothing about it that sounds wrong.